# @OneToMany conditional loading

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Can you please help me.
Using EclipseLink for JPA implementation.

Please help me to find solution for this. I have entity House.

```
<code>
Class Animals {
String typeOfCat;
 @OneToMany
  private List<Cat> whiteCatList;
@OneToMany
  private List<Cat> blackCatList;
}
</code>
```

When my entity is loaded, I would like to load List of collections conditionally. The reason is cat list for black cats have lots of records imagine 10,000 but I do not have to show all of them to users and do not want to load all of them. 
so would to load those collections based on typeOfCats.
Is there way to load collections conditionally. Please help me with that. 
Ideally was looking @Where clause of entity attribute, rather than class level.
This class is part of other class, whenever this class is loaded I would like to check attribute value of typeOfCates and load only some of the collection based on criteria I provide.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't know if there is a smarter way, but when loading the parent object you can just iterate the Animals and just call the getter-method (getWhiteCatList() for example) if your criteria are met. If you do this on an EJB they will load